# Shortname for My Documents in Windows 7

Tags: cmd.exe, window, filenames

I have a program that needs to access a c++ compiler that I have installed in the My Documents folder - say d:\My Documents

The program can't handle a space in the path and the path is already in double quotes. 
I have tried finding out the short name by using `dir /x` and `for %I in (.) do echo %~sI`. This just returns the full name of My Documents.
I have also tried `%userprofile%\documents` but the program doesn't recognise this.

Why can't I get the short name of this folder using this command? Is there another way to get the short name or a likely truncation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be looking at a link or shortcut.

The default location of "My Documents" is:

```
C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Documents
```

So if your %USERNAME% is "myname" you would reference:

```
C:\Users\myname\Documents
```

It sounds like you are using an old command.com program that needs DOS 8.3 filenames. In this case you would take the first six characters and add "~1" for the first item. If you had two items that shared the same first six characters then the next one would end in "~2" and so on. To be certain, you can run "dir /x" to see what short-names have been assigned to each folder.

In my final example I will show what it would look like for a long username in this format. The example username will be "longusername".

```
C:\Users\LONGUS~1\DOCUME~1
```

**Follow this pattern with your own username.**

If your "My Documents" is not in the default location or you want to dynamicaly find the location you would check the following registry location:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders
```

Comment: `dir /x` is more reliable. Suppose one creates three folders, `LongFolder1`, `LongFolder2`, and `LongFolder3`, then deletes the first and creates `LongFolder4`. Why guess what name to use when there's `dir /x`? Otherwise, good answer as in this simple case this answer did help the OP.

Comment: Ok, I added a note that you can use "dir /x" to find the name instead of guessing. I always guess and have never had a problem.

Answer (score 4):

`dir /x` will display the short filename for files and folders, if one exists. One will exist, if the long name is greater than the 8.3 character format.

For instance, here is an example of using `dir /x` in my user profile folder:

```
01/02/2018  05:35 PM    <DIR>                       .
01/02/2018  05:35 PM    <DIR>                       ..
10/16/2017  09:41 AM    <DIR>          ASDM~1       .asdm
11/01/2017  01:01 PM    <DIR>          GIMP-2~1.8   .gimp-2.8
11/20/2017  05:26 PM    <DIR>          NETWOR~1     .networkassistant
12/15/2016  09:54 AM    <DIR>          THUMBN~1     .thumbnails
11/16/2017  09:48 PM    <DIR>                       Contacts
07/17/2017  02:23 PM    <DIR>          DOCUME~1     Documents
01/03/2018  01:07 PM    <DIR>          DOWNLO~1     Downloads
03/14/2017  02:43 PM    <DIR>                       GNS3
12/19/2017  01:10 PM    <DIR>          GOOGLE~1     Google Drive
11/16/2017  09:48 PM    <DIR>                       Links
06/22/2017  07:20 AM    <DIR>                       OneDrive
```

Notice that the shortname is shown next to the long name.

Also notice that the standard for shortening the name is to remove spaces, shorten the name to 6 characters and add a ~1, capitalize all the letters, add the first 3 characters of the file extension. If there is a conflict, a ~2 will be added instead, and so on.

If we are to assume your documents folder is saved at `D:\My Documents` and that there are no other conflicting names, then the shortname will be `D:\MYDOCU~1`.

You likely can't use %userprofile% for the same reason you can't use long filenames. The program simply doesn't understand environment variables. And, it too is not using the shortname version.

Comment: He stated that he already failed to find it using "dir /x" I think he is looking in the wrong place.

Comment: That's just silly. If the accepted answer works, then `dir /x` works. The OP obviously didn't do it correctly.

Comment: Because he would need to know from where to run "dir /x". I told him from where. If he had a long username he would have to run "dir /x" from the users directory and then CD to that 8.3 username and run it again. In this case it would be faster to just type it in freehand because I can see what the correct 8.3 name would be by using the method I described in my answer.

Comment: Both good answers. Checking the registry was the important detail that HackSlash provided.